# Stanford NLP and Eclipse: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: eclipse, stanford-nlp

I know this is a common error but I am getting it in regards to edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP. I am using Java 1.8 and have tried with 1.7 as well. What should I be using with the NLP? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Stanford CoreNLP requires Java 1.8